# What are the benefits/consequences when deciding the fate of the Rachni Queen in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the mission 'The Attican Traverse: The Rachni' at the end of the mission you are faced with the decision to either free the Rachni Queen or leave her to the fate of her malevolent offspring. Given the variety of possibilities, dependent upon whether you've imported saves from ME1/ME2, what are the various possible outcomes of this decision? Also, what war assets will be gained or lost as a result?

I'm currently playing ME3 with a brand new (non-imported) character and it seems that the past history given to the player by default indicates that you have presumably killed the Rachni queen in past experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you leave the queen to die, you get Aralakh company as a war asset.

If you save the Real Queen (spared Queen in ME1), you get War Assets from Rachni workers, but Aralakh company dies.

If you save the Reaper Copy Queen (Killed Queen in ME1), you get War Assets from Rachni workers... until they betray you, removing them as a war asset, *and* permanently reducing the war asset value of the Alliance Marine Corp (I think you lose 100 or so), ***and*** Aralakh company dies.

Either way, Grunt's survival depends on whether or not you completed his loyalty mission in ME2 - if he's loyal, he lives, otherwise, he dies fighting off the swarm.

Comment: What's the assumed loyalty of Grunt for a non-imported character?

Comment: @MarcusSwope not loyal.

Comment: isn't grunt assumed dead from a non imported character and replaced with another Krogan that is similar to a non loyal grunt?

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer is all spoilers, taken from the [wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rachni#Mass_Effect_3):

> If you spared the Rachni queen in the original Mass Effect, the Reapers find it and indoctrinate her children, although not herself.
>
> Shepard has a choice to either save the queen (sacrificing Aralakh Company) or let her die (saving Aralakh Company). If she is saved, Aralakh is slaughtered, and Grunt makes a last stand holding off the rachni Husks called Ravagers. If Grunt wasn't loyal to the mission, then he will die, but if he was loyal, he will survive. If she is saved, rachni workers are sent to the Crucible project, where they are prized assets for their engineering capabilities, industrious nature, and good teamwork.
>
> If Shepard did not spare the Rachni queen on Noveria, the Reapers will artificially construct a Queen thrall in order to control a rachni army. Shepard can choose to spare this artificial queen even if the Commander killed the real queen. This queen will eventually betray Shepard, taking the Rachni Workers War Assets away and decreasing the numerical values of some Alliance fleet War Assets.

Answer (score 0):

The effects are minimal. Only affecting war assets to a small degree. if you saved the queen in the original game and had Grunt loyal in the second choosing to save her during the mission gets a net gain of 75 war assets over letting her die.

If you did not save her/didn't import a game saving the queen will actually harm your war assets from her workers turning on your people again, in such a case it's better to side with Grunt. Regardless of choice Grunt survives if loyal in the previous game, if not loyal Grunt only survives if sided with.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note (ik a little late) if you save the krogans you receive a drunken email from Grunt and Aralakh Company praising Shepard (and ryncol) doesn't affect war assets. But rather amusing which is why I like saving Aralakh even if the rachni die out

Answer (score 0):

I saved the Rachni queen with Grunt Loyal and the Original one saved in Mass Effect 1. In my war assets I have both Grunt, The Rachni Workers and Aralakh Company. Not sure what that's about...